# Spring Batch JAXB XML unmarshal targeting multiple XML nodes

Tags: java, spring-boot, jaxb, spring-batch, jaxb2

I'm using Spring Batch (with Spring Boot) to read an XML file using `StaxEventItemReader` in a `MultiResourceItemReader`. Batch reader is intended to target `<Receipt>` and process/write for each register from the XML-source.

The **problem** I have is that I need to write the `<Header>` contents together with every register. I was able to configure `Jaxb2Marshaller` in order to read receipts one-by-one (getting a callback to `process()` for each register), but I cannot figure out how can I make reader/unmarshaller to read both the `<Header>` and a `<Receipt>` each time.

Maybe I have to create a `ReceiptWrapper` class to hold both header + receipt? In that case, how to instruct `Jaxb2Marshaller` to do so? And how to annotate Wrapper class?
I'm a mess with annotations, `reader.setFragmentRootElementNames()` and `marshaller.setClassesToBeBound()`.

Is there any simple way to achieve that?

The aim is to concatenate the header at the beginning of every register.

**Note:** I created Header and Receipt classes via Eclipse JAXB code generation from an XSD I generated.

Here is the structure of the XML to read:

```
<ProcesosEIAC xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.tirea.es/EIAC/ProcesosEIAC ProcesosEIAC.xsd" xmlns="http://www.tirea.es/EIAC/ProcesosEIAC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
    <!-- [...] -->
</Header>
<Objects>
    <Receipt>
        <!-- [...] -->
    </Receipt>
    [...]
    <Receipt>
        <!-- [...] -->
    </Receipt>
</Objects>
```

Here is an excerpt of what I have:

```
// Don't know how this should be...
fileReader.setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[]{"ProcesosEIAC", "Header", "Receipt"});

Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(ReceiptWrapper.class /*, HeaderType.class, ReceiptType.class*/);
fileReader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I managed to make it work. In essence from what I've understood, to achieve the result, you must set the root elements of the fragments `StaxEventItemReader` is going to generate.

In my case:

```
fileReader.setFragmentRootElementNames(new String[]{ "Header", "Receipt" }
Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(HeaderType.class, ReceiptType.class);
fileReader.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
```

where `HeaderType.class` and `ReceiptType.class` are the JAXB-generated classes.

The trick was to define a common interface or base class for JAXB classes (e.g. `MyXmlTargetElement`) so that reader type declaration matches the unmarshalled objects:

```
StaxEventItemReader<MyXmlTargetElement> fileReader = new StaxEventItemReader<>();
```

This allowed to read elements sequentially one-by-one (including `<Header>`) and no wrapper class was necessary.

Then in the `process(MyXmlTargetElement item)` method of Batch ItemProcessor, I checked for the actual type of item using instanceof and when a header has been read, set it to a private member field (`lastHeader`). Then, when a `<Receipt>` comes, you already have the previously header stored in that member.

Comment: I have a similar requirement but i am getting ClassCastException. My Header cannot be casted to MyXmlTargetElement  in ItemProcessor.process(). Do you remember facing any problem like that ?

Comment: Does your HeaderType and ReceiptType classes implement MyXmlTargetElement?
Is that what you suggested ?

Comment: Hi @truekiller It is long ago since I worked on this, but that's how I did it, yes. If I recall correctly, I manually generated those JAXB classes (instead of using a plugin in the build), checked it into `src` and then I modified them to implement that interface. Can't remember much more about that right now.

Comment: Can you have a look at my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909123/copy-header-tag-in-xml-spring-batch-application