# Copy header tag in xml spring batch application

Tags: java, spring-boot, xml-parsing, spring-batch, spring-batch-stream

I am using `spring-batch` in `spring-boot` application. The Spring Boot version is `2.3.3.RELEASE`.

> What I intend to achieve

I have to `read a xml file` containing thousands of `Transactions` with `header tag` (fileInformation). Do some business logic on transaction and then write the file back with the updated values in transaction. I am using `StaxEventItemReader` for reading the file and `StaxEventItemWriter` for writing to the file. Then i have couple of `ItemProcessors` for handling the business logic. Xml file looks like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reportFile>
   <fileInformation>
      <sender>200GH7XZ60</sender>
      <timestamp>2020-12-23T09:05:34Z</timestamp>
      <environment>PRO</environment>
      <version>001.60</version>
   </fileInformation>
   <record>
      <transaction>
         <buyer><buyer/>
      </transaction>
      <transaction>
         <buyer><buyer/>
      </transaction>
      <transaction>
         <buyer><buyer/>
      </transaction>
   </record>
</reportFile>
```

> Problem that I am facing is with the value of header tags.

I have configured the `OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack` which generates the desired header tags but the value in those tags should be copied from the input file. As I am aware the `StaxWriterCallback` is initialized before reader, processor and writer. So I am not able to inject the value using `late binding`.
This looked like a basic requirement, but couldn't find any solution on `stackoverflow`.

> Here is the code snippets to configure spring batch job.

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

@Autowired
PIExtractorItemProcessor pIExtractorItemProcessor;

@Autowired
JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
 
@Autowired
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Value( "${eugateway.batch.chunk.size}" )
private int chunkSize;

@Bean
public Step jobStep(ItemStreamReader<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement> reader,
        CompositeItemProcessor<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement, 
        ProcessorWriterDto> processor,
        CompositeItemWriter<ProcessorWriterDto> writer,
        EdsClientItemWriteListener<ProcessorWriterDto> writeListener, 
        StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("extractAndReplacePersonalDataStep")
            .<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement, ProcessorWriterDto>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(reader)
            .processor(processor)
            .listener(writeListener)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
}

@Bean
public Job extractPersonalDataJob(Step jobStep, JobResultListener jobListener,
        JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory) {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("extractAndReplacePersonalDataJob")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(jobStep)
            .listener(jobListener)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public ItemStreamReader<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement> itemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[file.path]}") String path) {
    Jaxb2Marshaller transactionMarshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    transactionMarshaller.setClassesToBeBound (FileInformation.class, TransactionPositionReport.class);
    log.info("Generating StaxEventItemReader");

    return new StaxEventItemReaderBuilder<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement>()
            .name("headerTransaction")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource(new FileSystemResource(path)))
            .addFragmentRootElements("fileInformation", "transaction")
            .unmarshaller(transactionMarshaller)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack getOmegaXmlHeaderCallBack(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.sender']}") String sender,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.timestamp']}") String timestamp,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.environment']}") String environment,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.version']}") String version){
    return new OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack(sender, timestamp, environment, version);
}

@Bean
@StepScope
OmegaXmlFooterCallBack getOmegaXmlFooterCallBack(){
    return new OmegaXmlFooterCallBack();
}

@StepScope
@Bean(name = "staxTransactionWriter")
public StaxEventItemWriter<TransactionPositionReport> staxTransactionItemWriter(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.sender']}") String sender,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.timestamp']}") String timestamp,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.environment']}") String environment,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.version']}") String version) {
    String exportFilePath = "C:\\Users\\sasharma\\Documents\\TO_BE_DELETED\\eugateway\\outputfile.xml";
    Resource exportFileResource = new FileSystemResource(exportFilePath);

    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setSupportDtd(true);
    marshaller.setSupportJaxbElementClass(true);
    marshaller.setClassesToBeBound(TransactionPositionReport.class);

    return new StaxEventItemWriterBuilder<TransactionPositionReport>()
            .name("transactionWriter")
            .version("1.0")
            .resource(exportFileResource)
            .marshaller(marshaller)
            .rootTagName("reportFile")
            .headerCallback(getOmegaXmlHeaderCallBack(sender, timestamp, environment, version))
            .footerCallback(getOmegaXmlFooterCallBack())
            .shouldDeleteIfEmpty(true)
            .build();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public PIExtractorItemProcessor extractItemProcessor() {
    log.info("Generating PIExtractorItemProcessor");
    return new PIExtractorItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
public PIRemoverItemProcessor removeItemProcessor() {
    log.info("Generating PIRemoverItemProcessor");
    return new PIRemoverItemProcessor();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
CompositeItemProcessor<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement, ProcessorWriterDto> extractAndRemoveItemProcessor() {
    log.info("Generating CompositeItemProcessor");
    CompositeItemProcessor<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement, ProcessorWriterDto> itemProcessor = new CompositeItemProcessor<>();
    itemProcessor.setDelegates((List<? extends ItemProcessor<?, ?>>) Arrays.asList(extractItemProcessor(), removeItemProcessor()));
    return itemProcessor;
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public EdsClientItemWriter<ProcessorWriterDto> edsClientItemWriter() {
    log.info("Generating EdsClientItemWriter");
    return new EdsClientItemWriter<>();
}

@Bean
@StepScope
public OmegaXmlFileWriter<ProcessorWriterDto> omegaXmlFileWriter(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.sender']}") String sender,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.timestamp']}") String timestamp,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.environment']}") String environment,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.version']}") String version) {
    log.info("Generating OmegaXmlFileWriter");
    return new OmegaXmlFileWriter(staxTransactionItemWriter(sender, timestamp, environment, version));
}


@Bean
@StepScope
public CompositeItemWriter<ProcessorWriterDto> compositeItemWriter(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.sender']}") String sender,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.timestamp']}") String timestamp,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.environment']}") String environment,
        @Value("#{jobExecutionContext['header.version']}") String version) {
    log.info("Generating CompositeItemWriter");
    CompositeItemWriter<ProcessorWriterDto> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
    compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(edsClientItemWriter(), omegaXmlFileWriter(sender, timestamp, environment, version)));
    return compositeItemWriter;
 }  
}
```

Below is the  `OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack` class. Due to no late binding I always end up getting empty values  in header tag.

```
@Slf4j
public class OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack implements StaxWriterCallback {
    private String sender;
    private String timestamp;
    private String environment;
    private String version;
    
    public OmegaXmlHeaderCallBack(String sender, String timestamp, String environment, String version) {
        super();
        this.sender = sender;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.environment = environment;
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(XMLEventWriter writer) {
        XMLEventFactory factory = XMLEventFactory.newInstance();
        try {
            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "fileInformation"));

            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "sender"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters(sender));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "sender"));


            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "timestamp"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters(timestamp));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "timestamp"));

            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "environment"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters(environment));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "environment"));

            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "version"));
            writer.add(factory.createCharacters(version));
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "version"));
            
            writer.add(factory.createEndElement("", "", "fileInformation"));
            
            writer.add(factory.createStartElement("", "", "record"));
            
        } catch (XMLStreamException e) {
            log.error("Error writing OMEGA XML Header: {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new OmegaXmlHeaderWriterException(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `ItemProcessor` is below. I am setting the header data into `ExecutionContext` which was intended to be read by headerCallback (sadly not going to happen).

```
@Slf4j
public class PIExtractorItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement, ProcessorWriterDto> {

    @Autowired
    PersonalDataExtractor personalDataExtractor;
    
    @Value("#{jobParameters['submission.account']}") 
    private String subAccntId;
    
    @Value("#{stepExecution}")
    private StepExecution stepExecution;
    
    @Override
    public ProcessorWriterDto process(CustomHeaderTransactionXmlElement headerTransactionElement) throws Exception {
        FileInformation header = null;
        TransactionPositionReport transaction = null;
        if(headerTransactionElement instanceof FileInformation) {
            header = (FileInformation)headerTransactionElement;
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("header.sender", header.getSender());
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("header.timestamp", header.getTimestamp());
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("header.environment", header.getEnvironment());
            stepExecution.getExecutionContext().put("header.version", header.getVersion());
            log.debug("Header {} found.", header.toString());
            return null;
        } else {
            transaction = (TransactionPositionReport)headerTransactionElement;
            log.debug("NO header info found for transaction {}", transaction.getProcessingDetails().getCustomerTransactionId());
            log.info("Extracting personal data for transaction customer id {} and create EDS requestDto.", transaction.getProcessingDetails().getCustomerTransactionId());
            ProcessorWriterDto transferObject = new ProcessorWriterDto();
            transferObject.setEdsRequestDtoList(personalDataExtractor.extract(transaction, subAccntId));
            transferObject.setTransaction(transaction);
            return transferObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Links that have been referred by me :

- [accessing-the-executioncontext-values-in-headercallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52076902/accessing-the-executioncontext-values-in-headercallback-in-spring-batch)
- [How to read header tag by modifying setFragmentRootElementNames and marshaler in ItemReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41245452/spring-batch-jaxb-xml-unmarshal-targeting-multiple-xml-nodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step is doing too much. I would beak things down to two steps:

- Step 1: extracts the file information header and puts it in the job execution context
- Step 2: reads the file information header from the execution context and uses it in whatever step-scoped bean needed for that step (for example the stax callback in your case)

Here is a quick example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLEventWriter;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParametersBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepScope;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ExecutionContext;
import org.springframework.batch.item.xml.StaxWriterCallback;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class SO67909123 {

    @Bean
    public Step extractHeaderStep(StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return steps.get("extractHeaderStep")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    Map<String, Object> jobParameters = chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobParameters();
                    String inputFile = (String) jobParameters.get("file");
                    FileInformation fileInformation = extractFileInformation(inputFile);
                    ExecutionContext jobExecutionContext =  chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution().getExecutionContext();
                    jobExecutionContext.put("file.information", fileInformation);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

    private FileInformation extractFileInformation(String inputFile) {
        // TODO extract header from inputFile
        FileInformation fileInformation = new FileInformation();
        fileInformation.sender = "200GH7XKDGO3GLZ60";
        fileInformation.version = "001.60";
        return fileInformation;
    }

    @Bean
    public Step processFile(StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return steps.get("processFile")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> { // Change this to a chunk-oriented tasklet
                    Map<String, Object> jobExecutionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext();
                    FileInformation fileInformation = (FileInformation) jobExecutionContext.get("file.information");
                    System.out.println("Step 2: " + fileInformation);
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
        }).build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public StaxWriterCallback staxWriterCallback(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['file.information']}") FileInformation fileInformation) {
        return new StaxWriterCallback() {
            @Override
            public void write(XMLEventWriter writer) throws IOException {
                // use fileInformation as needed here 
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobs, StepBuilderFactory steps) {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(extractHeaderStep(steps))
                .next(processFile(steps))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SO67909123.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder()
                .addString("file", "transactions.xml")
                .toJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
    }

    static class FileInformation implements Serializable {
        private String sender;
        private String version;
        // other fields

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "FileInformation{sender='" + sender + '\'' + ", version='" + version + '\'' + '}';
        }
    }

}
```

This example shows the idea. You only need to write the snippet that extracts an xml tag from the file (only the header, see TODO). The `StaxWriterCallback` in that example is a step-scoped bean and can use the header from the execution context. Other step-scoped components from step 2 can also be configured in the same way (processor, listener, etc).